# What does it mean when "method exists but trait bounds not satisfied"?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and observed something that I couldn't reason against.

When I write

```
fn main() {
    ('a'..'z').all(|_| true);
}
```

The compiler reports an error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `all` found for type `std::ops::Range<char>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:2:16
  |
2 |     ('a'..'z').all(|_| true)
  |                ^^^
  |
  = note: the method `all` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `std::ops::Range<char> : std::iter::Iterator`
```

When I change it to

```
fn main() {
    (b'a'..b'z').all(|_| true);
}
```

it compiles.

What's happening here? What does Rust mean when it says `the method ... exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied`?

Comment: You can map to a char to achieve what you want, for example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=120f51cf16015dfdd244175b07c6ec22

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The method `all()` is a method of the `Iterator` trait, so you can only call it on types that implement that trait. The type `Range<char>` does not implement the `Iterator` trait, since a range of Unicode characters is not well-defined in the general case. The set of valid Unicode code points has gaps, and building a range of code points is not in general considered useful. The type `Range<u8>` on the other does implement `Iterator`, since iterating over a range of bytes has a well-defined meaning.

More generally, the error message tells you that Rust has found a method with the correct name, but that method does not apply to the type you call it for.

Answer (score 14):

What this means is that there is a trait in scope that has a function with that name, but that the object you are using does not implement such a trait.

In your particular case, the trait that contains the `all` method is [`std::iter::Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all), but your object `('a'..'z')` if of type `Range<char>` that does not implement it.

Curiously enough, your second example compiles because `(b'a'..b'z')` is of type `Range<u8>` that does implement `Iterator`.

You are probably wondering why `Range<char>` does not implement iterator. That is because there are invalid `char` values between valid ones, so these ranges just cannot be iterated. In particular, the only valid chars are those in the ranges `[0x0, 0xD7FF]` and `[0xE000, 0x10FFFF]`, IIRC.

---

UPDATE: It looks like since [Rust 1.45.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/96f387920c21a83fa620b1838066fd4c73c4b486), `Range<char>` does implement `Iterator`, so the OP code is now (since about 2020) correct.