# Why does a Rust HashMap not allow inserting a value with "no method named `insert` found for struct `HashMap`"

Tags: rust, hashmap

I have a struct that is created with an empty `HashMap` (`node_type_odds`). This hashmap will have values added by the user.

When I attempt to add keys and values to the hashmap after creation using `fn set_node_odds` it does not suggest the `insert` keyword which (as I understand it) is the primary way keys are inserted into hashmaps.

Why can't I add values to a hashmap that is contained in a struct?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

//The possible node types
pub(crate) enum node_type {
    Kernel,
    LSTM,
    Perceptron,
}

//The possible activation types
pub(crate) enum activation_type {
    Binary,
    Linear,
    Sigmoid,
    Tan,
}

//The constructor that holds the seed values for the Mesh Networks.
pub(crate) struct constructor {
    node_type_default: node_type,
    node_type_odds: HashMap<node_type, f32>,
    activation_type: activation_type,
}

impl constructor {
    //Set the default node and initialize default values
    pub(crate) fn new() -> constructor {
        constructor {
            node_type_default: node_type::Perceptron,
            node_type_odds: HashMap::new(),
            activation_type: activation_type::Sigmoid,
        }
    }

    //Set the default node to a custom value
    pub(crate) fn set_default_node(&mut self, default_node: node_type) {
        self.node_type_default = default_node;
    }

    //Set the odds of each type of node to appear
    pub(crate) fn set_node_odds(&mut self, Type: node_type, Value: f32) {
        **//Here I attempt to insert a value with the key of type and a value of X.
  //Insert is not suggested however.**

        //THIS CODE SNIPPET DOES NOT WORK AS INSERT IS NOT SUGGESTED, IT IS HOWEVER THE INTENDED RESULT
        self.node_type_odds.insert(Type, Value);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `insert` found for struct `std::collections::HashMap<constructor::node_type, f32>` in the current scope
  --> src/constructor.rs:45:29
   |
4  | pub(crate) enum node_type {
   | -------------------------
   | |
   | doesn't satisfy `constructor::node_type: std::cmp::Eq`
   | doesn't satisfy `constructor::node_type: std::hash::Hash`
...
45 |         self.node_type_odds.insert(node_type::Perceptron, 3 as f32);
   |                             ^^^^^^ method not found in `std::collections::HashMap<constructor::node_type, f32>`
   |
   = note: the method `insert` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `constructor::node_type: std::cmp::Eq`
           `constructor::node_type: std::hash::Hash`
```

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Comment: You need to implement `Eq` and `Hash` on `node_type`, otherwise the hash map is basically useless.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [What does it mean when “method exists but trait bounds not satisfied”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56296864/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: The error message from the compiler would actually tell you that's the problem.

Comment: It does not, otherwise I wouldn't be here.

Comment: *otherwise I wouldn't be here* — people ask questions about why their IDE doesn't do X or Y all the time; your question doesn't clearly indicate what it is you are asking.

Comment: Sven Marnach, that could be the issue. Ill see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more what you don't understand about the error message? *`insert` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `node_type: Eq`
           `node_type: Hash`* feels understandable to me.

Comment: Literally everything you just said. Chapter 8.3 of the documentation did not mention the need to implement traits to change a HashMap.

Comment: The key type of the hash map needs to implement these traits. If you use, say, `String` or `i32` as the key type, you don't need to implement these tratis since they are already implemented. If you want to use a custom type as the key type of the hash map, you need to implement the traits yourself, but you can most of the time get away with simply deriving them.

Comment: Yup. It's a hard requirement based on the implementation of a *hash*map — the keys need to be able to be hashed. They also need to be able to be compared for equality, as multiple unique values might hash to the same key.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Sven and Shepmaster. This has shown me that I may need to take another approach to this problem.